# Intent JSONObject to another activity

Tags: java, android, json

I want to pass JSONObject to another activity in the else section in he below code so i can use profile details in the other activity,

```
public void redirectToActivity(JSONObject result, JSONObject profile){

    try {           
        String status = result.getString("status");

        if (status.equals("204")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMenu.class);
            intent.putExtra("user", "email");
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } 
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            //here I want to pass JSONObject profile to RegisterActivity
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to pass a `JSONObject` you can use a `String`. For instance:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("profile", profile.toString());
 intent.putExtra("result", result.toString());
 this.startActivity(intent);
```

`toString()` implementation of the `JSONObject`, class rncodes the object as a compact JSON string. In your `RegisterActivity`, to retrieve the String:

```
 String profile = getIntent().getStringExtra("profile");
 JSONObject profileJSON = new JSONObject(profile)
```

Comment: how to receive these profile data from RegisterActivity?         Intent intent = getIntent();
String JSONObject = intent.getStringExtra("JSONObject"); correct me please if im wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass objects easily to another activity, if the object is not parcelable. To achieve this, you can create a class. For example name it, RunTimeData.

In this class create a static JSONObject.

```
public class RunTimeData{
    public static JSONObject object;
}
```

So whenever you want to store the data, you can store it as follows.

```
RunTimeData.object=result;
```

When you want to use this, in another activity use,

```
JSONObject result=RunTimeData.object.
```

And finally when you are sure that you are not going to use this value anymore in the program, null it.

```
RunTimeData.object=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Blackbelt is right, but another valid solution is to use a simple object implementing 
[Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

e.g.

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.setTitle(myJsonObject.getJSONObject("title").opt("val").toString());
...
intent.putExtra("someCoolTAG", obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use global data

```
public class GlobalData extends Application{
    JSONObject jsonObj;
}

else{
    ((GlobalData)getApplication).jsonObj = myJsonObj;
    startActivity(new Intent(...));
}
```

You also need to declare in manifest in application tag
    android:name=".GlobalData"

Comment: **Don't do this**, there is absolutely no need too override the Application class just to create a global object to pass an object between activities. It's inefficient and extremely bad practise.